# map a numpy array to a double (unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray')

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have a numpy array

```
xCoord = 25
yCoord = 35
xEntent = 5
yExtent = 8

np.array((xCoord, yCoord, xCoord+xEntent,yCoord+yExtent))
```

i want to map it to a value

```
confidence = 3.25

confidence_map = {}

confidence_map[np.array((xCoord, yCoord, xCoord+xEntent,yCoord+yExtent))] = confidence
```

when i try to do this, it shows "unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'" error

how can i map this numpy array to this value?
is there any other way to map without dict?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries accept only immutable objects as keys. Since your `np.array` seems simple enough, you could just convert it to a tuple.

```
  confidence_map[tuple(my_array)] = confidence_value
```

However, take care that the values in the array don't change after inserting it to the dict, otherwise you'll get stale confidence values